# How to add a button to dynamically created layout for going back to previous activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity which is dynamically created from the main Activity using  setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null,x) , i have written this code

```
public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();  

    public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int x) {  
        super(context, attrs);  
        LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(getContext());  
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        Button b=new Button(getContext());
        b.setText("Back");
        ll.addView(b);
        setContentView(ll);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }
}
```

But i am getting an error on the line "setContentView(ll);"  saying "The method setContentView(LinearLayout) is undefined for the type SingleTouchEventView "
I have to place a button on this activity so that a person can go back to previous activity.

Comment: But why are you trying to set content view for your SingleTouchEventView? Probably you should set content view only for the activity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no method called setContentView() in the class view.. so you get such error...

in order to remove that error, create the instance of your mainactivity and invoke this method with thatone..

Example if your main activity is HomeActivity then

```
public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
private Paint paint = new Paint();
Private HomeActivity custom_view=null;
private Path path = new Path();  
public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int x) 
{  
super(context, attrs);  
LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(getContext());  
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
Button b=new Button(getContext());
b.setText("Back");
ll.addView(b);   custom_view.setContentView(ll);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't add a button.  Just let the built-in [Back](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) button do its thing, or override it if you need custom functionality.  For purposes of displaying your View, you probably need to start with a new Activity, Dialog or Fragment, not a view.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
public class SingleTouchEventView extends LinearLayout {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();  

    public SingleTouchEventView(Context context) {  
        super(context);  
        this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                                           (MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
        setLayoutParams(parms);
        Button b=new Button(getContext());
        b.setText("Back"); // better: getContext().getString(R.string.someString);
        this.addView(b);
        b.setLayoutParams(parms);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }
}
```

and then inside your Activity, set Your Content View like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    SingleTouchEventView v = new SingleTouchEventView(this);
    setContentView(v);
}
```

Comment: I added this code but i am unable to see the button

public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();
LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(getContext());
public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int x) {
super(context, attrs);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
Button b=new Button(getContext());
b.setText("Back");
ll.addView(b);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

Comment: sorry. First its very hard to read Code inside comments. Please avoid long lines inside them.  And I don't see your Activity Code. please update this inside your Question. Second, I see, that you still don't have taken my code (extending View instead of LinearLayout). I updated some parts I left out the first time.

Comment: Thanks for your help but by doing this i can only see the button whereas i can't draw anything on the canvas.
I want the button as well as my canvas so that i can draw something there.